# RPM installation shows failed IUP dependencies

Tags: rpm, iup

rpm package shows Failed dependencies even though it is present in /usr/lib (by the way, the library is IUP)
this is the error
error: Failed dependencies:
    libiup.so is needed by  <package-name>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the library was installed without RPM (e.g. a manual `make install`). That can be verified by asking the database `rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/lib/libyourlibname.so`. If it tells you that nothing provides it, then that is why it failed.

The work around would be to do "`--nodeps`" on the RPM command line. This isn't recommended unless you are *sure* that it's the correct file.